# If statement within updateOrInsert() in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a controller that gets data from a woocommerce database and adds it to another database via a cronjob. We want to add an additional field of SKU in the db. however, the SKU needs to be mapped to either of 2 records in the woocommerce database with the logic.

If _variation_id = 0
then
SKU = _product_id
else
SKU = _variation_id

Where _variation_id and _product_id are both coming from the same source db.

Here is what i tried but keep getting an error.

```
 $woo_product_id = $order_itemmeta->where('meta_key', '_product_id')->pluck('meta_value')->first();

            $woo_variation_id = $order_itemmeta->where('meta_key', '_variation_id')->pluck('meta_value')->first();

           if ($woo_variation_id == 0) {
                            $SKU = $woo_product_id;
                        }
                        else {
                            $SKU = $woo_variation_id;
                        };
 DB::table('orders')->updateOrInsert(['order_item_id' => $order->order_item_id],[
 'SKU' => $SKU,
 ]);
```

Where am i going wrong? Sorry, i am very new to this

Comment: what error you are getting

Comment: @JohnLobo here's the error ----- syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting ']' {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting ']' at /home/lenold/webapps/invoices/app/Http/Controllers/OrderController.php:87)
[stacktrace]

Comment: remove semicolon from };

Comment: also post full code of OrderController.php